# Как указать при загрузке у клиента модуля socket.io порт, если он не локальный

Tags: node.js, сервер, socket.io, node-modules

Здравствуйте. Я работал с socket.io только локально, по этому на калиентской части указывал:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('http://localhost:4000/');
</script>
```

теперь же я загружаю приложение в [Now](https://zeit.co/now) и у меня socket не может подключится к серверу, т.к. сервер больше не локальный.
На серверной части я указываю:

```
io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function() {
console.log('server is working! '+ this.address().port);
});
```

и вот я столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как мне с сервера передать **process.env.PORT** на клиентскую часть, чтобы socket.io смог работать

я попробовал провернуть такое:
на сервере:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.get('/setHost', function(req, res){
res.statusCode = 200;
res.end(''+ port);
});
```

на клиенте:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
port;
xhr.open('GET', 'setHost', false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
} else {
alert( xhr.responseText );
port = xhr.responseText;
}
const socket = io(port);
```

но даже когда я приложение загружаю в интернет, мне выводит 4000 в алерте. Что может быть не так?

Comment: А где у вас клиентская часть хостится?

Comment: на [Now](https://zeit.co/now)
путь выглядит примерно так:
https://horchynskyi-chat-oxnlnsirkt.now.sh/
каждый раз разный.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

В блоке `listen` добавь в `app.locals.port` вот это `this.address().port` передай шаблонизатору и подставь в `<script>window.PORT = {port};</script>`. Далее на фронте считай порт в переменную в твоем классе и после не забудь удалить переменную `PORT` из `global` - это обязательно.